# Angular 1.6: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

I have tried to get this child parent component relationship to work but i get mesage:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module lesson due
>   to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   lesson.lesson-attendance due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module lesson.replacement-new due to: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'controller' of undefined
>       at $CompileProvider.registerComponent [as component]

Here is my code.

lesson-attendance.module.js (parent module):

```html
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import { LessonAttendanceComponent } from './lesson-attendance.component';

//modules
import { ReplacementNewModule} from './replacement-new/replacement-new.module'

export const LessonAttendanceModule = angular
.module('lesson.lesson-attendance', [uiRouter,
  ReplacementNewModule
])
.component('lessonAttendance', LessonAttendanceComponent)
.config(($stateProvider) => {
    'ngInject';
    $stateProvider.state('LESSON', {
      url: '/tunnit/:id',
      template: '<lesson-attendance></lesson-attendance>'
    })
})
.name;
```

lesson-attendance.component.js (parent component):

```html
export const LessonAttendanceComponent = {
 templeteUrl: 'app/lesson/lesson-attendance/lesson-attendance.html',
 controller:  class LessonAttendanceCtrl{
 
    constructor($stateParams, $q, LessonApi, CourseApi, $location, DateService, ModalService, AuthStatus, StudentService, $uibModal) {
      'ngInject';  
      this.params = $stateParams;
      this.q = $q;
      this.lessonApi = LessonApi;
      this.courseApi = CourseApi;
      this.location = $location;
      this.dates = DateService;
      this.modals = ModalService;
      this.status = AuthStatus;
      this.studentSvc = StudentService;



      this.lessonAttendance = [];
      this.students = [];
      this.lesson = {};
      this.course = {};
      this.creatingNew = false;
    }

    $onInit() {
          
      this.lesonApi.getLesson(this.params.id)
      .then(res => {
        this.lesson = res.data;
        this.date_time = this.dates.parseDateTime(res.data._time, res.data._date);
        return this.courseApi.getCourse(this.lesson.course); 
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.course = res.data;
        return this.courseAPi.getStudentsByCourse(this.lesson.course)
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.students = res.data;
        return getLessonAttendances();
      })
      .then(res => getReplacements());
    }

 

    

    changeLocation() {
      if(this.status.getRole() == "teacher") this.location.path("/opettajat/"+this.status.roleObj.id+"/profiili");    
      else this.location.path("/ryhmat/" + this.lesson.course);
    }

    initLessonAttendances() {
      for(let i in this.students){
        this.lessonAttendance.push({
          student: this.students[i].id,
          status: 'ei merkitty',
          lesson: this.params.id,
          firstname: this.students[i].firstname,
          lastname: this.students[i].lastname,
        });
      } 
    }

    getLessonAttendances() { 
      this.lessonApi.getLessonAttendances($stateParams.id)
      .then(res => {  
        this.lessonAttendance = res.data;

        if(this.lessonAttendance.length<=0){
          this.creatingNew=true;
          initLessonAttendances();
        } 
      });

    }
    

    getReplacements(){
      this.lessonApi.getReplacementsByLesson(this.params.id)
      .then(res => this.replacements = res.data);
    }

    addLessonAttendances(data) {
      this.lessonApi.addLessonAttendances(data)
      .then(() => changeLocation());
    }
    

    updateLessonAttendances(data) { 
      this.lessonApi.updateLessonAttendances(data)
      .then(() => changeLocation());
    }
    

    
    openAddReplacement() {
      $uibModal.open({
        component: 'replacementNew',
        resolve: {
          missed_lesson: () => billId
        }
      }).result.then(
        result => this.getContent(),
        reason => console.log(reason)
      );
    }
    
    

    
    saveLessonAttendances() {

      let a,b,c;
      
      if(this.creatingNew){
        a = addLessonAttendances(this.lessonAttendance);
      }else{
        a = updateLessonAttendances(this.lessonAttendance);
      }

      b = this.lessonApi.updateLessonReplacements(this.replacements);
      c = this.lessonApi.updateLesson(this.lesson);

      return $q.all([a, b, c]);

    };

    deleteLesson() {
      const modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Peruuta',
            actionButtonText: 'Poista ',
            headerText: 'Poistetaan tunti',
            bodyText: 'Oletko varma että haluat poistaa tunnin ryhmältä?'
        };

        return ModalService.showModal({}, modalOptions)
        .then(() => this.lessonApi.deleteLesson(this.params.id))
        .then(() => this.location.path('/ryhmat/' + this.course.id));

    }

    changeStatus(att) {
      if(att.status == 'poissa')att.status = 'paikalla';
      else if(att.status == 'paikalla')att.status = 'poissa';
      else if(att.status == 'ei merkitty')att.status = 'paikalla';
    }

    openLessonEdit() { 
      this.modals.openModal('app/lesson/views/partials/lessonEditModal.html', {lesson: this.lesson})
      .then(() => this.$onInit());
    }
   

  }
}
```

lesson-attendance.html (parent view):

```html
<div id="lesson-attendance">
  <div class="centered-page" id="main-container">
   <h1>{{course.name}} ({{lesson._date | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy'}})</h1> 

   
   <!--Modal buttons-->
   <div class="search-bar" permission permission-only="['ADMIN']">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">  
      <button permission permission-only="['ADMIN']" id="openLessonEdit" class="btn btn-success"  ng-click="openLessonEdit()">Muokkaa tunnin tietoja</button>    
      <button permission permission-only="['ADMIN']" id="deleteLesson" class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="deleteLesson()">Poista tunti</button> 
     </div>
    </div>   
   </div></br>

   
   <!--Normal students-->
   <div class="panel panel-area">
    <h3 class="centered">Oppilaat</h3>
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="attendance in lessonAttendance | orderBy:'lastname'">  
     <div class="list-item">
      <div class="flexbox">
         <div class="col"> <h4 style="width:100%;">{{attendance.firstname}} {{attendance.lastname}}</h4> </div>
         <div ng-click="changeStatus(attendance)" class="col">
          <button style="width:100%; height:100%;" ng-class="{'btn-default': attendance.status == 'ei merkitty', 'btn-success': attendance.status == 'paikalla', 'btn-danger': attendance.status == 'poissa', 'btn-warning': attendance.status == 'korvannut'}" class="btn">
           {{attendance.status}}
          </button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>  
   </div></br>

    
   <!--Replacement students-->  
    <div ng-show="replacements.length > 0">
     <div class="panel panel-area">
        <div class="flexbox">
          <h3 class="centered">Korvaajat</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openReplacementModal()">Lisää korvaaja</button>
        </div>
     
     <div class="list" ng-repeat="replacement in replacements track by $index">
      <div class="list-item">
       <div class="flexbox">
          <div class="col"> <h4 style="width:100%;">{{replacement.firstname}} {{replacement.lastname}}</h4> </div>
          <div ng-click="changeStatus(replacement)" class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
           <button style="width:100%; height:100%;" ng-class="{'btn-default': attendance.status == 'ei merkitty', 'btn-success': replacement.status == 'paikalla', 'btn-danger': replacement.status == 'poissa'}" class="btn">
            {{replacement.status}}
           </button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div><br>

   <div class="panel panel-area">
     <h3 class="centered">Julkiset muistiinpanot</h3>
     <textarea style="width: 100%; height:10em; max-width: initial;" ng-model="lesson.public_note"></textarea>
   </div>
   </br>
   <div class="panel panel-area">
     <h3 class="centered">Omat muistiinpanot</h3>
     <textarea style="width: 100%;height:10em; max-width: initial;" ng-model="lesson.private_note"></textarea>
   </div>


        
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="addLessonAttendance" class="btn btn-success"  ng-click="saveLessonAttendances()">Tallenna</button>
      <a id="returnButton" href="#/ryhmat/{{course.id}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Palaa ryhmään</a>
    </div>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

replacement-new.module.js (child module):

```html
import { ReplacementNewComponent } from './replacement-new.component';

export const ReplacementNewModule = angular
.module('lesson.replacement-new', [])
.component('replacementNew', ReplacementNewComponent)
.name;
```

replacement-new.component.js (child component):

```html
export const ReplacementNewComponet = {
  bindings: {
    resolve: '<',
    modalInstance: '<'
  },

  templateUrl: 'app/lesson/lesson-attendance/replacement-new/replacement-new.html',

  controller: class ReplacementNewCtrl {

    constructor(LessonApi) {
      'ngInject';
      this.lessonApi = LesonApi;
      this.replacement = {};
    }

    $onInit() {
      this.studentApi.getStudentsAbsentByLesson({
        lesson: this.resolve.missed_lesson
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.missedStudents = formatDates(res.data);
      })
    }

    createReplacement(student) {



      this.lessonApi.addLessonReplacement({
        missed_lesson: null, 
        replacement_lesson: resolve.lesson,
        student: student,
        status: 'paikalla'
      })
      .then(() => this.modalInstance.ok());

    }
    
  }
}
```

replacement-new.html (child view):

```html
<div>
  <h4>Valitse korvaaja</h4>
  <div class="list" ng-reapeat="students in $ctrl.missedLessons">
    <div role="btn" bg-click="$ctrl.createReplacement()" class="list-item">{{Lastname}} {{Firstname}}</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

I have used similar component architecture in my whole app bu now ther seems to be something im missin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No errors if i remove replacement-new.module and all references to it.

Comment: Can you try importing without brackets? just import LessonAttendanceComponent .... instead of import {LessonAttendanceComponent} ...same for other imports

Comment: export const ReplacementNewComponet has a typo

Comment: Ohh thank you! Need better tooling and autocorrection :D